# Signed permutation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A signed permutation matrix $P$ is a generalized permutation matrix whose nonzero entries are $±1$.

Every signed permutation matrix $P$ can be written as a matrix product $P=D L$  where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with only $±1$ entries, and $L$ is the matrix obtained from taking the absolute value of each of the entries of $P$. The matrix $L$ is a permutation matrix. The $(i, i)-entry$ of the diagonal matrix $D$ is the sign of the non-zero entry in the $ith$ row of $P$.

I would like to show that $P^k =I$ for some positive integer $k$. Please any help.

I know that $L^m =I$ for some positive integer $m$, but I dont know how to use this note to answer my question.
I need the proof without using the fact that Signed permutation matrix is a finite group.

Comment: this will help a lots.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are only finitely many such matrices and they form a group under matrix multiplication so the order of any of the elements divides the order of the group.

This is a ridiculously large bound on the order.

Comment: Thank a lots but I need the proof without using the fact that Signed permutation matrix is a finite group. anyway thanks for your answer .Best